# Precedence of CSS style selector for closer element with same strength definition

Tags: html, css

I have 2 css files, each of which correspond to a theme - Light, Dark.
Both of them have the exact same selectors, just different color/background color, etc. definitions.
The idea is that I can style any component/module in dark or light theme by simply adding `light-theme` or `dark-theme` in it's wrapper div. But if I don't add this explicitly, then whichever theme class is used in the body should get applied. BUT, if there's a theme at body and a theme at component wrapper, then the wrapper theme should prevail.

Take this example:

```
<html>
<body class='light-theme'>
  <div class="component-wrapper dark-theme">
    <div class="navbar">
      <nav class="nav-item">Link 1</nav>
      <nav class="nav-item">Link 2</nav>
    </div>
  </div>
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

My dark.css has

```
.dark-theme .navbar { background-color: black; }
```

My light.css has

```
.light-theme .navbar { background-color: white; }
```

The problem:
My thought was - since navbar has .dark-theme as the closest ancestor, it would get styled as per dark-theme.
Unfortunately, what's happening is - the order in which the css files are getting loaded, (light-theme loads last in my case), and since the selector strengths are same, light-theme prevails.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score -1):

After fiddling around with it a bunch, I figured it out. In your example you used single-quotes instead of double-quotes. `class='light-theme'` vs `class="light-theme"`.

Here's a working version:

```css
.light-theme .navbar { background-color: white; color: black;}
.dark-theme .navbar { background-color: black; color: white;}
```

```html
<html>
<body class="light-theme">
  <div class="component-wrapper dark-theme">
    <div class="navbar">
      <nav class="nav-item">Link 1</nav>
      <nav class="nav-item">Link 2</nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not really - I you move  `light-theme` underneath darktheme in your css, the problem is still there. dingle vs double quotes does nothing. ie. the only thing you achieved was to reorder the load of the themes styles.

Comment: @Stender Oh, you're right. Well I have absolutely *no* idea why this is happening. This seems like it should be super simple to solve. But I'll let you guys know if I ever find a solution.